# Use events on jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, slickquiz

I have been working with this **[jquery plugin](https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz)** to use its event on my code but I had no luck.

here is the list of events:

> events.onStartQuiz (function) Default: empty; - a function to be
>   executed once the quiz has started.
>
> events.onCompleteQuiz (function) Default: empty; - a function to be
>   executed the quiz has completed; the function will be passed two
>   arguments in an object: options.questionCount, options.score

can someone help me to know how to use events on this plugin.

https://jsfiddle.net/pcvkqwut/

```
$(function () { 
    $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({
    });
});
```

Comment: I also found this : https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz/issues/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are properties of the `options` object you need to pass to `slickQuiz()` when you instantiate it:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({
    events: {
      onStartQuiz: function() {
        console.log('started');
      },
      onCompleteQuiz: function() {
        console.log('completed');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/npykqdwg/)